# "darauffolgend" oder "darauf folgend"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ich erstelle eine Beschreibung für eine Applikation, welche von der gesamten Firma verwendet wird und mit meinem Namen steht. Da die Firma über 600 Mitarbeiter beschäftigt, möchte ich in der Beschreibung keinerlei Schreibfehler haben.

Ich habe folgenden Teilsatz:

> Wird das Programm ohne Parameter gestartet, wird man [darauffolgend][darauf folgend] aufgefordert, (...)

Bei den beiden Wörter in den eckigen Klammern bin ich mir nicht sicher, welche Version geschrieben wird. Soweit ich bisher herausgefunden habe, werden beide Versionen verwendet, je nach Kontext.

Also welche Version sollte ich verwenden? Und weshalb?

Comment: `Ich bin [...] am erstellen` - Rheinland?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zur Beantwortung der Frage:

Es sind beide Varianten *drauffolgend* und *darauf folgend* zulässig ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/darauffolgend)).

Die Beschreibung ist zwar grammtikalisch richtig und wird auch verstanden, man würde aber eine knappere Formulierung wählen:

> Wird das Programm ohne Parameter gestartet, [dann] wird man aufgefordert, (...)

Das *dann* ist im obigen Beispiel optional, da ein zeitlicher Zusammenhang schon im einleitenden Satz mit *"wird..."* hergestellt ist.

Noch knapper, oder um eine Wiederholung von *wird* zu vermeiden, ist auch folgende Varianten denkbar:

> Wenn man das Programm ohne Parameter startet, wird man aufgefordert (...)
>   Wird das Programm ohne Parameter gestartet, muss man (...)

Comment: Dem stimme ich zu. Die jetzige Formulierung finde ich auch deshalb ungünstig, weil das „man“ sich auf jemanden bezieht, der zuvor nicht eingeführt wurde. Ich würde daher Deine Variante mit „Wenn man...“ vorziehen oder alternativ: *Wird das Programm ohne Parameter gestartet, fordert es den Benutzer auf, ... Wird das Programm ohne Parameter gestartet, wird der Benutzer aufgefordert, ...*

Comment: Sehr gute Antwort. Ich finde den Anstoss von @CarstenSchultz ebenfalls sehr spannend. Inwiefern ist `(...), der zuvor nicht eingeführt wurde.` zu verstehen? Also mit einer bestimmten Person identifiziert?

Comment: @dTDesign: es ist zwar in Bedienungsanleitungen unüblich, ich finde es aber trotzdem gut, wenn man die Benutzer direkt anspricht: *"Wenn Sie das Programm ohne Parameter starten, werden Sie gebeten..."*.

Comment: @Takkat: Richtig, Aktiv ist meistens einfacher zu lesen als Passiv.